# Unity File Explorer for android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to build an app with a file upload option. to select the file and get its filelocation and filename and upload it to the php, mysql database and save the file through a folder but the EditorUtility does not exist in the current context error showsup when im building it to an apk file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;

public class FileManager : MonoBehaviour
{
string fileName, filePath, savePath, path;
public GameObject uifilepath;

    public void OpenExplorer()
    {
        path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel ("Image Explorer " , " ", "png,jpg,pdf,jpeg,docx");
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        filePath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
    
        savePath = Application.dataPath + "/classwork/" + fileName;
    
        uploadImage();
    }
    
    void uploadImage()
    {
        if(path != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("File Name: " + fileName);
            Debug.Log("File Location: " + filePath);
    
            uifilepath.GetComponent<Text>().text = fileName;
    
        }
    }

}
```

I understand that the UtilityEditor is only for the editor of unity i would like to ask if there is another way i could do what I want to do?

Comment: You can file picker https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeFilePicker  or if you have knowledge of android you can create your own use it